# Filling a DropDownListFor() on View for TableA with all the values for a field in TableB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

I'm developing an MVC5 WebApp with an Oracle backend. My main Table/Model Class has a text field (`varchar2(4000)`) currently called "OWNER" -- this is just a plain text field with no foreign attributes or links of any kind. Instead of having users type in any given value, I'd like to make input easier and have them select the user from a dropdown filled with all the values from another DB table (ex.) `TBL_OWNERS`.

In my main controller (ex.) `CTRL_MainController` I am attempting to fill a `Viewbag.Owner_List` with all the values for `OWNER_NAME` field from `TBL_OWNERS`:

```
Viewbag.Owner_List = new SelectList(db.TBL_OWNERS, "OWNER_NAME", "OWNER_NAME");
```

Then on my View I want to use `Html.DropDownListFor` to bind the values where the currently selected `OWNER` for the record appears in the list by default when the View loads/the change is bound when the controller posts the save action.

So far I have gotten `@Html.DropDownList("Owner_List", (SelectList)ViewBag.Owner_List, new { @class = "col-md-10 form-control" })` to populate by using `ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.TBLE_OWNERS, "OWNER_NAME", "OWNER_NAME");` on my controller, but being `Html.DropDownList` and not `Html.DropDownListFor()` no values or changes are bound to my Model.

Can anyone assist with the syntax for setting up this functionality with `Html.DropDownListFor()` to where my changes are bound with the model?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PtMRVw

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle Alundra. I was attempting it in a MetaData class I created in my DAL, and some fiddling of my own got the following working: [Controller]: `ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.TBL_OWNERS, "OWNER_NAME", "OWNER_NAME");` | [View]: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OWNER, (SelectList)ViewBag.Owner_List, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", @id = "selectOwner" })`.